# Is my query optimized?

Tags: mongodb

I have a query to get the latest 10 chats but I can't tell if it's optimized properly. I'm also not sure how to optimize such a basic query.

```
db.chats.find({}).sort({time: 1}).explain()
```

It returns:

```
{
  "cursor" : "BtreeCursor time_1",
  "isMultiKey" : false,
  "n" : 12,
  "nscannedObjects" : 12,
  "nscanned" : 12,
  "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 12,
  "nscannedAllPlans" : 12,
  "scanAndOrder" : false,
  "indexOnly" : false,
  "nYields" : 0,
  "nChunkSkips" : 0,
  "millis" : 0,
  "indexBounds" : {
    "time" : [
      [
        {
          "$minElement" : 1
        },
        {
          "$maxElement" : 1
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  "server" : "c1213.candidate.14:11219",
  "filterSet" : false
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the last 10 chats, you should add a `.limit(10)`, otherwise you ll get every documents of your collections.
As you can see, actually you have 12 objects scanned for your query, just imagine if you had 1.000.000 documents (which can come really quickly I guess when we talk about chats).

Also for the sort, you can use the auto generated _id, which has a time embeded in: `ObjectId("507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e").getTimestamp()
=> ISODate("2012-10-15T21:26:17Z")`, it's usually easier to handle, and you don't need extra modules to set a creation timestamp. But you don't have to of course.

So this works too : `.sort({_id:-1})` : you want *-1 because it's descending*, so it will sort with newests first(what you are asking).

This is not that much 'optimized', but is more reflecting (or more correct) what you want to do as far as I understand your question:
`db.chats.find({}).sort({_id: -1}).limit(10).explain()`